# using variable limits in gnuplot command "set yrange [min:max] if called from python script

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have python script which has an input arguments of min and max of y range  and I want to plot the graph accordingly

> test.py -m miny -i maxy

inside the python script 
gnuplotcmds.append('set yrange [miny:maxy]')

my question is , how can i use variable limits in the gnuplot command as when running this line it always read miny and maxy as strings not variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `miny` and `maxy` are python variables, you must use something like

```
gnuplotcmds.append('set yrange[{0}:{1}]'.format(miny, maxy)
```

If you want to have a tight yrange, you could also use

```
gnuplotcmds.append('set autoscale yfix')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to parse the values from the commandline within python:

```
import sys

miny=0.0
maxy=0.0
for i in len(sys.argv)-1:
    if(sys.argv[i] == "-m"):
        miny=float(sys.argv[i+1])
    if(sys.argv[i] == "-i"):
        maxy=float(sys.argv[i+1]
```

This is a very simple way to do that, but it does not check your parameters. For example, if there is no number after a `-i` in your command line, you run into trouble. There are more sophisticated methods like the `getopts` module, but for now, this code does the job.

As in Christhoph's answer, you can now use

```
gnuplotcmds.append('set yrange[{0}:{1}]'.format(miny, maxy)
```